# BigQuery only return first 500 columns. How can I view the full table data?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table which may have around a couple thousands of columns. When I run my query it only return the 500 columns. Is there a way to view the full table?

"Showing the first 500 columns for performance reasons.
Consider modifying your query to show fewer columns."

Answer (score 0):

Showing too many columns impacts the browser's performance. Even with 500 columns displayed you may find your browser glitching.

The best way to get access to the columns you are interested in is to the suggestion and query only a subset of columns.

If you need access to all the columns at the same time, you could export the results of your original query as a CSV or another supported export format and access the export with a tool that would alloy you to display all the columns.

Another way to get access to all the columns within the UI would be to split your original query into multiple queries where each has 500 or fewer attributes selected.

Answer (score 0):

The initial Google sheet will show a sample of 500 rows.  To get up to 25,000 rows, click the `Extract` button and extract the data to a new Google Sheet.  You should be good to go from there.